# socialmedia status comment system

Tags: php, comments, status

I am trying to create a post-comment system, with simple php-mysqli, as simple as it is, it does not seem to give me the result in the fashion I want i.e:

---POST MESSAGE----
-----comments-----

Here is the code I used:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('php_includes/db_conx.php');
$user=$_SESSION['user'];

$o =mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT post.id,post.post,post.date,post_comments.poster,post_comments.comment,post_comments.date FROM post LEFT JOIN post_comments ON post.id=post_comments.post_id AND post.username='$user' ORDER BY post.date");

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($o,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $status= $r['post'];
    $date=$r['date'];
    $com=$r['comment'];
    $pid=$r['id'];
    $poster=$r['poster'];
    if(count($pid) > 1){

    }

    echo $status.'|'.$pid.'|'.$date.'<br>'.$poster.':'.$com.'<hr>';

}

?>
```

It seems to duplicate the post for each comment for same post.

Not sure am making sense, but i will appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, add post id to your query's `ORDER BY`. That will ensure that your post and all its comments appear together, and only once. (I'd recommend adding `post_comments.date` as well so your comments will appear in order, but that won't be necessary to get the grouping working.)

```
... ORDER BY post.date, post.id, post_comments.date
```

Then keep track of the post id as you go. Echo the post information only when the post id changes.

```
$id = null;   // initialize to null

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($o, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $pid = $r['id'];
    $status = $r['post'];
    $date = $r['date'];
    $com = $r['comment'];
    $poster = $r['poster'];

    if ($pid !== $id) {
        echo $status.'|'.$pid.'|'.$date.'<br>';    // new post, so echo post info here
        $id = $pid;                                // $id becomes new post id
    }
    if ($com) {
        echo $poster.':'.$com.'<br>';              // echo comment if present
    }
}
```

One other thing that will probably cause some trouble is that you have selected both `post.date` and `post_comments.date` in your query, so I'm not sure which one will be in `$r['date']`. It would be a good idea to alias at least one of those columns to disambiguate them.